# Add to dictionary from array of keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

For the last couple of days I have been struggling with the following issue

I need to set a key and a value deep in a dictionary of dictionaries. I know the keys to the dictionary where I want to set a key but I cannot figure out how to get there.
The keys are stored in an array.

Say, I have a dictionary with the following keys and the value of each key is another dictionary.

```
- myDict
    - A
      - A
        - A
        - B
      - B
        - A
        - B
    - B
      - A
        - A
        - B
      - B
        - A
        - B
```

I also have the following array:

```
[A, A, B]
```

This means, that I want to set a value for a key in the dictionary at A->A->B.
This equals the following:

```
[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"A"] objectForKey:@"A"] objectForKey@"B"] setValue:myValue forKey:myKey]
```

Does anyone know of a way where I can achieve this?
I imagine that I should keep a reference to the dictionary, iterate over the objects in the array and go to the "next level" in the dictionary and keep a reference to this and when the last object in the array has been reached, set the value for the key. My problem is, that I can't figure out how to pull this off. To hold a reference to the dictionary, when I go to the next level, I need initialize a new dictionary, right? This causes me to create a new dictionary only containing the objects for the current level and thereby I will not end up setting a value for a key in the original dictionary.

Any code examples or pseudo codes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried recursion? (I don't expect it the nesting to be too deep, but even if so, it is possible to convert recursion to loop with stack)

Comment: I don't see at which point new dictionary would be initialised...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you would just do `[yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@"."]` to get a keypath, then use `valueForKeyPath:` to get the appropriate value.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been looking for! Easy and elegant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this, not saying this is the 'exact' answer, but should get you on your way to figuring out your exact needs.

```
for(NSString* key in [myDict allKeys]) {

    NSString *yourValue = ....
    NSDictionary *dict = [[myDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:key];// Will get you to A->A

    for(NSString *levelKey in [dict allKeys]) {

    //Setting Value for A->A->(A) & A->A->(B)

          [dict setValue:yourValue forKey:levelKey];      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer should be ignored. Instead, use the approach that @Chuck posted.**

I ended up writing the two methods below which will solve the problem. This is inspired by @nhahtdh.
These method would be fit great in a category but I have never written a category before. Someday I may make these a category. Should anyone feel like doing so, please post the result here.

```
/**
 *  Sets the value in a dictionary with a keypath. Uses either the first or the last key in the keypath as the key to set the value for.
 *  @param value Value to set.
 *  @param dictionary Dictionary to set the value in.
 *  @param path Path for the key. Last or first object is used as the key for the value.
 *  @param readFromEnd Whether or not to read the path from the end.
 */
 + (void)setValue:(id)value inDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary withKeyPath:(NSArray *)path readFromEnd:(BOOL)readFromEnd
{
    NSMutableArray *mutablePath = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:path];
    NSString *key;
    if (readFromEnd)
    {
        key = [mutablePath lastObject];
        [mutablePath removeLastObject];
    }
    else
    {
        key = [mutablePath objectAtIndex:0];
        [mutablePath removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [self setValue:value forKey:key inDictionary:dictionary withKeyPath:mutablePath readFromEnd:readFromEnd];
}

/**
 *  Sets the value in a dictionary with a keypath.
 *  @param value Value to set.
 *  @param key Key for the value.
 *  @param dictionary Dictionary to set the value in.
 *  @param path Path for the key.
 *  @param readFromEnd Whether or not to read the path from the end.
 */
+ (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key inDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary withKeyPath:(NSArray *)path readFromEnd:(BOOL)readFromEnd
{
    if (path.count == 0)
        [dictionary setValue:value forKey:key];
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *mutablePath = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:path];
        NSString *currentKey;
        if (readFromEnd)
        {
            currentKey = [mutablePath lastObject];
            [mutablePath removeLastObject];
        }
        else
        {
            currentKey = [mutablePath objectAtIndex:0];
            [mutablePath removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        [self setValue:value forKey:key inDictionary:[dictionary objectForKey:currentKey] withKeyPath:mutablePath readFromEnd:readFromEnd];
    }
}
```